# Future Passive Progressive?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, future, progressive-aspect, passive-voice

Does some future passive progressive tense exist, such as:

> He will ***be*** ***being*** interviewed by police."

as a counterpart to the past passive progressive tense, such as:

> He ***was being*** interviewed by police."

Comment: Short answer: of course.

Answer (score 1):

It is informal, looks very odd and should be replaced with future simple:

> He will be interviewed by police.

After all **interview** itself relates/points to a progressive activity.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the progressive here serves the function of indicating simultaneous actions:

> Don't call him at 10am, he will be being interviewed by police.
>
> He won't be able to take your call, as he will be being interviewed by police.